# When to raise UnicodeTranslateError?

Tags: python, python-unicode

The standard library documentation says:

```
exception UnicodeTranslateError
    Raised when a Unicode-related error occurs during translating.
```

But translation is never defined. Doing a grep through the cpython source I can't see any examples of this class being raised as an error from anything. What is this exception used for and what's the difference between it and the Decode exception which seems to be used much more frequently?

Comment: The only hint I see is this extract from the stream recoder section in the codecs docs: "The StreamRecoder translates data from one encoding to another, which is sometimes useful when dealing with different encoding environments."  Perhaps the error occurs while translating one encoding to another?

Answer (score 0):

[Unicode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unicode) has room for more than 1 million code points. (At the moment "only" about 150,000 of them are assigned to characters, but in theory more than 1M can be used.) The number of all available code points, written as a binary number, has 21 binary digits, which means you need 21 bit or at least 3 byte to encode all code points.

But the most used characters have unicode code points then need less than 10 bit, many even less than 8 bit. So, a 3-byte encoding would waste a lot of space when you use it to encode texts that contain mainly characters with low code points.

On the other hand a 3-byte encoding has disadvantages when processing in modern computers because the CPU prefers packages of 2, 4 or 8 byte.

And so there are different encodings for unicode strings:

- [UTF-32](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-32) uses 32-bit fields to encode unicode characters. This encoding performs very fast in computers, but also wastes a lot of space in memory.
- [UCS-4](https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/aix/7.1?topic=8-ucs-4-utf-32) is just another name for UTF-32. The number 4 means: exactly 4 bytes (which are 32 bit).
- [USC-2](https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/aix/7.1?topic=8-iso10646-ucs-2-unicode) uses 2 byte and therefore 16-bit fields. You need only half of the memory, but not all existing unicode code points can be encoded in UCS-2.
- [UTF-16](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-16) also uses 16-bit fields, but here also 2 of these fields can be used together to encode one character. So also UTF-16 can be used to encode all possible unicode codepoints.
- [UTF-8](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-8) uses 1-byte-fields. So in theory you need between 1 and 3 byte to encode every code point, but you also must add the information, if a byte is the start byte of a code point, and how many bytes the code point is long. And if you add these control bit to teh 21 data bit, you get more than 24 bit in total, which means: you need up to 4 byte to encode every possible unicode character.

There are even more encodings for unicode: [UTF-1](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-1), [UTF-7](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-7), [CESU-8](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CESU-8), [GB 18030](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GB_18030) and many more.

And the fact, that there are many different encodings make it necessary to translate from one encoding to another in some situations. And when you want to translate for example UTF-8 to UCS-2 you will get in trouble if the original text contains characters with code points out of the range that UCS-2 can encode. And in this case you should through a UnicodeTranslateError.